# How to exclude items without submenus in my css style definition?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm making a menu for my website.

```css
/*General styles for body*/
span, a, p, label {
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #767676;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-shadow: 5px 4px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
label:hover {
  color: hotpink;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-shadow: 5px 4px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

/*Style for the first level menu bar*/
ul#menu{
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu > li{
  margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
  max-width:30%;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
 box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

label{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:0 18px 0 18px;
  line-height:3.5em;
  transition:background 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
}

label:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:50%;
  right:25px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-top:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-bottom:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-left:4px solid transparent;
  border-right:4px solid transparent;
  transition:border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;
  }

label:hover,
input:checked ~ label{background:rgba(200,255,138,.4);}

input:checked ~ label:after{
  border-top:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-bottom:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition:border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}

/*hide the inputs*/
input{display:none}

/*show the second levele menu of the selected voice*/
input:checked ~ ul.submenu{
  max-height:300px;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*style for the second level menu*/
ul.submenu{
  max-height:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  background:#fff;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
  min-width:100%;
}

ul.submenu li a{
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow:0 -0.2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
  transition:background .3s;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover{
  background:rgba(50,160,90,.2);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>

<ul id="menu">
   <li>
    <a href="#">
    <input id="check01" type="button"/>
    <label  for="check01">just button</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="check02" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
    <label for="check02">more stuff here</label>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">stuff1</a></li>
      
  <li >
    <input id="check03" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
    <label for="check03">bunch of other stuff</label>
    <ul class="submenu" style="background:#e7e7e7">
      <li><a href="#">bunch 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bunch 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li><a href="#">stuff 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 
<br>
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</article>
```

I've modified a few examples I've found to my liking except for one thing - the little arrow showing next to the "button" item. Which is suppost to show only next to dropdown menus. Now, it's there because there is a rule for all `<li>` tags under `#menu` but is there an elegant way to exclude those without submenus? This menu is already quite hairy and all the solutions I can come up with only make it worse.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question. Noob in distress is not an appropriate question title for SO. Keep in mind, that future readers should be able to seach and find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The littel arrow is defined in the css with

```
label:after{
...
}
```

To exclude the labels that you want to be only a button, you can add a class attribute to that labels and then exclude labels with that class from your css declaration for labels with

```
label:not(.buttonLabel):after{
  ...
}
```

```css
/*General styles for body*/
span, a, p, label {
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #767676;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-shadow: 5px 4px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
label:hover {
  color: hotpink;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-shadow: 5px 4px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

/*Style for the first level menu bar*/
ul#menu{
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu > li{
  margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
  max-width:30%;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
 box-shadow: 5px 4px 27px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

label{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:0 18px 0 18px;
  line-height:3.5em;
  transition:background 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
}

label:not(.buttonLabel):after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:50%;
  right:25px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-top:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-bottom:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-left:4px solid transparent;
  border-right:4px solid transparent;
  transition:border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;
  }

label:hover,
input:checked ~ label{background:rgba(200,255,138,.4);}

input:checked ~ label:after{
  border-top:0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-bottom:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition:border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}

/*hide the inputs*/
input{display:none}

/*show the second levele menu of the selected voice*/
input:checked ~ ul.submenu{
  max-height:300px;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*style for the second level menu*/
ul.submenu{
  max-height:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  background:#fff;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
  min-width:100%;
}

ul.submenu li a{
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow:0 -0.2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
  transition:background .3s;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover{
  background:rgba(50,160,90,.2);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>

<ul id="menu">
   <li>
    <a href="#">
    <input id="check01" type="button"/>
    <label for="check01" class="buttonLabel">just button</label>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="check02" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
    <label for="check02">more stuff here</label>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">stuff1</a></li>
      
  <li >
    <input id="check03" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
    <label for="check03">bunch of other stuff</label>
    <ul class="submenu" style="background:#e7e7e7">
      <li><a href="#">bunch 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bunch 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li><a href="#">stuff 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 
<br>
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping somethig like that exists. The only way I could think of was overriding the first button with some style (didn't work) or making a whole new class identical to the one for labels except for the arrow.. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to edit the title of your question.